# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function_construct' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) on line 4

Tags: php, mysql

```html
<?php 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 require_once('..\includes\class-db.php');
 $db = new DB;
?>
```

I am getting an error in line 4 I don't know why 
Thats my Error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function_construct' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmc\includes\class-db.php on line 4

Please help me out here "Thanks in advance"

Comment: Could you share class-db.php code

Answer (score 0):

Refactor _construct() to __construct(). Notice the double underscore!

Comment: now it is showing this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function__construct' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmc\includes\class-db.php on line 4

Comment: please help me out

Comment: @ReynoldRoy share your class-db.php code